# Where are the 3.5e errata?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, errata

I am posting this question as in all the previous answers that I have found the links are expired.
Do the errata for each book of D&S 3.5 still exist?

Comment: Hey Digius, is see that the links on the duplicate question are not working. The thing to do here is to bounty that question, asking for updated answers. Would you like me to go ahead and do that?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov thank you very much for the information. I am not practiced with bounty so I would be glad if you could do that. Thank you very much

Comment: You should see an option to mark this as a duplicate in the header of the question somewhere. I’ll go ahead and throw up a bounty on the dupe target.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov thank you very much again. I am sorry I cannot find a way to close this. I tried to close by selecting that it is a duplicate of "how do I quick find the errata.." but is not accepted by the system saying that there is no accepted answer. Please close it down if you can.

Comment: No worries, close votes will sort things out soon enough.